# Why iPad show small screen size

Tags: ios, ipad

When I download an iOS app from the Appstore to my iPad it shows as small screen size. I want to know what is the condition behind that. It shows like that way because of it only for iPhone? or else if it is universal app or iPad app will it display same way when I install it?

Because my client is asking about one application he searched from the ipad display under both categories iPad and iPhone. But when it installed it shows in small screen size. Is there any connection between app type and this iPad display size?

I want to know although app is universal will it going to show in small screen size

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an app is truly universal, it will have seperate views for both `iPad` and `iPhone`.

If you're seeing a small screen on the `iPad`, it's because there is no `View` defined for the `iPad`. Therefore, it's not universal.

**Here is the run down:**

- All applications built for the `iPad` and `iPhone` are built on a
  platform called `iOS`.
- An application built for the `iPhone` can run on the `iPod Touch`,
  `iPhone` and `iPad`.
- An application built for the `iPad` can only run on the `iPad`.
- Because the `iPad` allows you to run pretty much any `iOS` application, it will allow you to find them in the app store.

Now just because an app runs on the `iPad`, it doesn't mean that it's built for the `iPad`.

If you are seeing an application on the `iPad` with a very small `View` that doesn't fit, it's because that app is specifically made for the `iPhone`.

Now there are these special cases - apps that are `Universal`. These `Universal` apps are specially designed to be used effectively on both `iPhone` and `iPad`. For each `iPhone` `View`, there's an `iPad` `View`. You'll know if an application is `Universal` because it'll have a `+` sign in the top right corner of the application icon.

A `Universal` app always looks the right screen size, whether on `iPad` or `iPhone`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The iPad will allow you to download iPhone apps from the app store.

The only way you can tell if an app is universal is if it has a little '+' sign in the top right of the application icon.

Does it have one of those?

Comment: but my client said he has searched another application it shows not only under the iPhone. But still it shows in small screen size? So how can It display under both catergories when search from the iPad.

Comment: I checked from my mac, I cannot see such a + sign

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to get at, but I'll try and explain what I think you need to know. Refer back to the post ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your application supports only **iPhone**, though it can run on iPads too. If you want your application to be run on all the devices change the settings to **Universal**, then you will have to design your views separately for iPhone and iPad..